# Are you able to see the data used in place of missing data in lmer and emmeans?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, emmeans

I am running lmer in R for a two-way (condition x time) repeated mixed linear model in R. I have two groups and a pre- and post-test measurement. I am using emmeans to determine pairwise comparisons. I have some missing data and was wondering if there is a way to see what numbers were ultimately used in the model to calculate the estimated marginal means?

For example, I have a participant who had a missing pre-test value and another missing a post-test value for a dependent variable. Is there any way to see the data set ultimately used to calculate the estimated marginal means after these missing data points have been handled?

Thanks.

I have looked through the R environment tab for my lmer effect and am not able to see anything that lines up with what I am asking.

Comment: Hello,

It is useful for us to have an example of code that shows the problem. How did you impute the missing data? If you just ran the model on the dataset with NAs included, I believe that lme4 just drops those rows so they are not in your model

Comment: (Almost) all of the information that `emmeans` uses flows through the coefficient estimates and their covariance matrix, if that helps. The "almost" is because it may use population-level averages or cell occupancies to decide what values of non-focal parameters to use, or how to weight averages across categories.